# Get ChildItem from only files of specific folders

Tags: powershell

I try to export files of specific named Folders:

`Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Test' -Name -Recurse -File  > C:\Test\Test.txt`

I get a list like:

```
content.csv
Test.txt
Folder 1\INTERESTED_FOLDER\a - Kopie.txt
Folder 1\INTERESTED_FOLDER\a.txt
Folder 1\Neuer Ordner\ttt.txt
Folder 1\Neuer Ordner - Kopie\ttt.txt
Folder 2\INTERESTED_FOLDER\b - Kopie.txt
Folder 2\INTERESTED_FOLDER\b.txt
Folder 2\Neuer Ordner\ttt.txt
Folder 2\Neuer Ordner - Kopie\ttt.txt
```

But what i want is:

```
Folder 1\INTERESTED_FOLDER\a - Kopie.txt
Folder 1\INTERESTED_FOLDER\a.txt
Folder 2\INTERESTED_FOLDER\b - Kopie.txt
Folder 2\INTERESTED_FOLDER\b.txt
```

I tried with -Filter "*INTERESTED*" etc. but then i only get

```
C:\Test\Folder 1\INTERESTED_FOLDER
C:\Test\Folder 2\INTERESTED_FOLDER
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Could try this ```get-childitem “c:\test” -recurse -include “a*.txt”,”b*.txt” | out-file “c:\test\results.txt”```

Comment: You just need to add wildcards to your filter: `-Filter *INTERESTED*`

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you want the FullNames of the files (so their names **including** the path).

If that is the case, remove the `-Name` switch and filter on the `DirectoryName` property like:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Test' -Recurse -File |
Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match 'INTERESTED_FOLDER' }).FullName |  # also matches 'MY_INTERESTED_FOLDER_123'
Set-Content -Path 'C:\Test\Test.txt'
```

Alternatives for the Where-Object clause:

```
# also matches 'MY_INTERESTED_FOLDER_123'
Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -like '*INTERESTED_FOLDER*' }
```

or if you are looking for a precise match on the complete folder name

```
# does NOT match 'MY_INTERESTED_FOLDER_123'
Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -split '[/\\]' -contains 'INTERESTED_FOLDER' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a *wildcard search* using the `-Filter` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Test' -Name -Recurse -File -Filter *INTERESTED_FOLDER* > C:\Test\Test.txt
```

If for example, you were interested in finding the files in **INTERESTED_FOLDER** but also only the files that are `.txt` you could do:

```
-Filter *INTERESTED_FOLDER*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-Name` parameter affects your capabilities because you are returning strings instead of `FileInfoObjects`. You may then use `Where-Object` to capture everything.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Test' -Name -Recurse -File | 
    Where {$_ -match '\\INTERESTED_FOLDER\\'} |
        Set-Content c:\test\test.txt
```

Note that the matching above assumes `INTERESTED_FOLDER` is not a direct descendent of your path. If that is a possibility, then your match expression needs to be updated to `\\?INTERESTED_FOLDER\\`.